# Persistent Storage with Vue 3, Vuex 4, and Electron

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuex, vuejs3

What is the best path toward running **Vue 3** (via Vite) with **Vuex** (4.X) and **Electron** together in a way that allows for offline storage (saving the Vuex store and rehydrating on startup)?

The aim is to have the user interact with settings (e.g. a checkbox to display the welcome page or not) and have that persist after electron is restarted ([screenshot of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgrYB.png)).

I have been looking through examples and various libraries (e.g. https://github.com/BetaHuhn/vuex-electron-store) to no avail, most are still using Vue 2.X.

I have forked my initial codebase from https://github.com/yingpengsha/electron-vite-quick-start, adding Vuex as well.

Any examples or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you come up with any solution?

Comment: Nope, I have dropped this project for the time being.